# Ignore Errors for a specific file in the Error List in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error, visual-studio-2013

I am including a file in a Visual Studio 2013 solution, giving a ".vb" extension to the file.  The file is not a valid Visual Basic file, and I know that, but it's a derivative of VB (a custom macro for custom software which, when attempting to validate as though it were "real" VB causes validation errors).  I am giving it the ".vb" extension because, aside from the errors generated in the Error List, the syntax highlighting is incredibly helpful.

I would like to be able to omit these errors in the Error List, because they get in the way when I have "legitimate" errors elsewhere in the solution.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new project.  I chose "Empty Project (Visual Basic)", but this works with whichever project type you choose, I believe.
2. Add a new ".vb" file.
3. Add this code:

> Option Explicit On
>
> Sub Main()
>
> Dim s As String = [111] 'This is 100% valid in the custom macro, but in VB it generates an "Identifier expected." error in the Error List.
>
> End Sub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to solve a problem that didn't truly exist.  As long as the project isn't set to build, the errors will only appear in the Error List when the file is open.  If the file is closed, they do not show, and this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Select the file in the Solution Explorer window.  In the Properties window, change the Build Action property from "Compile" to "Content".  You probably want Copy to Output Directory set to True, it isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Changing the Build Action has no effect.  I don't need it in the output directory (the question didn't specify, I acknowledge), but changing Copy t Output Directory also has no effect.

Comment: Works just fine on my machine, like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with a .vb file, but I had the same issue with a sql file. For this filetype I could right click and turn off intellisense for that file. This did not work for a .cs file I just tested - not sure if filetype is the reason.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic contact. About your deleted PSE question: it was wrongly downvoted and deleted in my opinion, but I can't do anything to save it. 1) The size of the things with near-c speed decreases and not increases (for us). 2) The electrons don't have a fixed position, and a fixed size as we can see it in popular books. They are more like a cloud. Oversimplified, in every point of the spacetime, you have a probability that you find there an electron. If an electron moves quickly, the size of this cloud will decrease (against oversimplified - the correct formulation is also over me).